# buttons and js not working, iframe wont redirect

Tags: javascript, html, button, iframe

I am using a homepage that has an iframe at the bottom/middle. There are buttons with corresponding javascripts that make the iframe go to different pages. for some reason the buttons have ceased to work, here is my code:

```js
function reloadIFrame() {
 document.getElementById("myIframe").src="./Home/main.html";
}
function reloadIFrame2() {
 document.getElementById("myIframe").src="./Home/Codestack/";
}
function reloadIFrame3() {
 document.getElementById("myIframe").src="./Home/Drawblog/";
}
function reloadIFrame4() {
 document.getElementById("myIframe").src="./Home/HourOfCode/";
}
function reloadIFrame5() {
 document.getElementById("myIframe").src="./Home/Services/";
}
```

```html
<div>
<button onclick="reloadIFrame();" style="border:none;color:#000000;padding:none;width:0;"><img src="t2-1.png" alt="Title" align = "left"></button>
<h3>&nbsp;</h3>
<h3>&nbsp;</h3>
<button onclick="reloadIFrame2();">   Codestack</button>
<button onclick="reloadIFrame3();">   Drawblog</button>
<button onclick="reloadIFrame4();">   Hour of code</button>
<button onclick="reloadIFrame5();">   Services</button>
<h4>&nbsp;</h4>
</div>
<center>
<center><iframe src="./home/main.html" width="630" style="display: block; border: none; height: 100vh; width: 100vw; height: 1700;" id ="myIframe"></center>
</div>
```

thank you for taking time to make a response.

Comment: First thing first: Why not using one function with a param like: `reloadIframe('./Home/Codestack/')`? Second: Your iframe don't have a closing tag.

Comment: Learn to use the console (F12), and check for errors, that way it won't be *"for some reason"*, you'll actually know why it doesn't work

Comment: ur correct tyr good job (btw @adeneo i checked console, nothing)